# When going through a maze, my recursive method stops prematurely

Tags: java, recursion, path-finding

I've been having an issue with my code where my recursive method suddenly stops traversing through the maze I have set up for a reason I can't identify. My maze is stored in a 2D array where 1's are seen as walls and 0's are seen as the path. My code always begins at the coordinates (0, 1).

```
public int[][] mazeSearch(int xCoord, int yCoord, int[][] mazeGrid, int counter){
//the current coordinates
String currentPosition = "(" + xCoord + ", " + yCoord + ")";


//if the maze position is part of the pathway...
if(mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] == 0){

  
  //BASE CASES
  //check if we are on the right edge of the board
  if(xCoord == mazeGrid.length - 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
  if(xCoord == mazeGrid.length + 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
  //check if we are on the left edge of the board
  if(yCoord == mazeGrid[yCoord].length - 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
  //check if we are on the 
  if(yCoord == mazeGrid[yCoord].length + 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
  

  //////

  //a 2 is placed in this spot to indicate the path that has been taken
  mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] = 2;
  
  //////
  
  //this goes through the maze and checks the areas around the current coordinate 
  if(mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord + 1] == 0){
    return mazeSearch(xCoord + 1, yCoord, mazeGrid, counter + 1);

  }else if(mazeGrid[yCoord + 1][xCoord] == 0){
    return mazeSearch(xCoord, yCoord + 1, mazeGrid, counter + 1);

  }else if(mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord - 1] == 0){
    return mazeSearch(xCoord - 1, yCoord, mazeGrid, counter + 1);

  }else{
    return mazeSearch(xCoord, yCoord - 1, mazeGrid, counter + 1);

  }
  
}

return mazeSearch(xCoord, yCoord, mazeGrid, counter);


}
```

The counter is automatically at 0 and is there so that my code doesn't end at the beginning.

This is what the unmarked maze looks like:

```
1111111
0000000
1111111
```

And this is what the console prints out when the method is done:

```
1111111
2200000
1111111
```

Is there something in my code that stops the method prematurely? Or did I not account for a situation? I'm sorry, I'm still learning recursion and it is more difficult than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

You swapped X with Y in the base checks:

```
  //BASE CASES
  //check if we are on the right edge of the board
  if(xCoord == mazeGrid.length - 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
```

Here `mazeGrid.length` is the number of rows of the grid (so the Y) and you compare with X, since you have 3 rows in your test case it stops when X = 2

```
  if(xCoord == mazeGrid.length + 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
```

This check looks useless, what is length + 1?

```
  //check if we are on the left edge of the board
  if(yCoord == mazeGrid[yCoord].length - 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
```

Again, `mazeGrid[yCoord].length` is the width of the grid and you compare it with your current Y

```
  //check if we are on the 
  if(yCoord == mazeGrid[yCoord].length + 1 && mazeGrid[yCoord][xCoord] != 2 && counter != 0) { 
    System.out.println(currentPosition);
    return mazeGrid; 
  }
```

Also this should be removed.